# line spacing not working in NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I have a custom text view which I built with `CoreText`. I'm setting the attributes on my text in the following manner:

```
self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.fontName size:self.fontSize];

self.paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
self.paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment;
self.paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing;
self.paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = indent;
self.paragraphStyle.headIndent = indent;
self.paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -indent;

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   self.paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                    self.font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                    self.textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    [self.text insertAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: text] atIndex:self.cursor.position];
[self.text addAttributes: attributes range:NSMakeRange(self.cursor.position, 1)];
```

I didn't notice for the longest time that the `lineSpacing` wasn't working at all! I've read on other questions that this was a bug in iOS6, however in iOS7 I'm still getting the same trouble. Some people say to mess around with `minimumLineHeight` and `maximumLineHeight`, but I've only gotten unpredictable results with that. And I'm unable to change `NSFontAttribute` (it's needed so I can save the attributes using CoreData).

I stumbled upon this when I started trying to adapt foreign keyboards to my app and I noticed the fonts for Chinese, Arabic, Japanese, and Russian all had massive gaps of space between the lines of text which I'm not able to adjust.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem of somehow being able to adjust the `lineSpacing`?